# Android Webview - can't disable cache

Tags: caching, socket.io, android-webview

I'm using webview in my app which is loading remote web page, which is then using `socket.io` (node.js) via xhr-pooling.

Problem is that I can't disable caching of received data through `socket.io`.
For example, every 10 seconds my node server does `io.emit`, and my webview receives it and saves it in:

> /data/data/...../webviewCache

I do not want my webview anything to save, because as time passes number of those files is just rising and they aren't helping my app run faster...

I've tried:

```
browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);   //(2 is LOAD_NO_CACHE)
browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```

but neither of those works. My webview is still saving files to the cache folder.

At this moment, I've set up timer which is emptying cache folder every 60 seconds but that's not solution I would like to release in production...

Am I missing something here or there is bug with disabling cache within android?

**UPDATE 1:** After whole day of debugging I've found out something interesting. 
Logcat shows two interesting things: **saveCacheFile** and **getCacheFile**

Then I've decided once again to try turn off the cache...

```
browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

That actually caused that WebView wasn't loading files from cache anymore, but it was still saving them. Log cat says something like this:

```
saveCacheFile for url .../socket.io/1/xhr-polling/BLNN28E7S4PZJsy2pWaF?t=13537
```

So I believe actual question would be, how to prevent webview from **SAVING** cache files on every request.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding random string in the query part of your URL? This trick works under some cases.

Comment: It's not an issue retrieving data from cache, the problem is that Android keeps saving files and unnecessary uses space.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to send "Cache-Control: no-store" in the HTTP response header.